# Angular running an older version of the project from somewhere

Tags: angular, starling-server

probably due to a mis-keyboard press the angular is running a 2 day old project file and not running the current one on $ ng serve. Any changes I make to the files, does not show-up in the result. It means it is serving files from somewhere else, how can I know the location and make the changes to work it with the original project.
I've tried to uninstall all the packages and reinstalled, including the CLI but not working. There is no duplicate file in the project directory and the directory from where I am running the project is the correct one.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: This sounds obvious, but just double check that you're running the `ng serve` command from the correct directory (that's probably not it, but just to make sure). If that's not the issue, then posting your angular.json file here might help diagnose what's going wrong

Comment: Thanks, the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kill all the processes.  Find the dist folder and delete it.  Then restart.

I'm guessing that you have either a running process and/or the dist folder hasn't been correctly updated.

Comment: Thanks, the issue has been resolved with as per your suggestion.